# XML -> XSLT -> Word for-each not looping

Tags: xml, xslt

I've updated my SQL client from MySQL Query Browser to MySQL Workbench.
With that upgrade my XML format changed and my XSLT don't work anymore. It will only show the first item.

Here is a simplify version of the XML and XSLT, it's Nessus output send to a MySQL database.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>

    <ROW>
        <Niveau>Haute</Niveau>
        <Nom>Some vulnerability</Nom>
        <Solution>Some Solution</Solution>
        <cve>CVE-2006-1234, CVE-2006-5615</cve>
        <bid>11263, 11291</bid>
        <Number>5</Number>
    </ROW>

    <ROW>
        <Niveau>Haute</Niveau>
        <Nom>Some Other Vulnerability</Nom>
        <Solution>Apply the security patch.</Solution>
        <cve>CVE-2006-1742, CVE-2006-1743</cve>
        <bid>20584, 20585</bid>
        <Number>23</Number>
    </ROW>

    <ROW>
        <Niveau>Moyenne</Niveau>
        <Nom>Yet another vulnerability</Nom>
        <Solution>Do this and that</Solution>
        <cve></cve>
        <bid></bid>                
        <Number>2</Number>
    </ROW>


</DATA>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
      <xsl:text>progid="Word.Document"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <w:wordDocument
      xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">

      <w:body>
        <xsl:for-each select="DATA/ROW">
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t><xsl:value-of select="Nom"/></w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </w:body>
    </w:wordDocument>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I then parse that in a script that merge the two in a Word document. It use to create as many table as I had entries. But now I only get the first line.
I'm pretty sure it has to do with either `<xsl:template match="/">` or `<xsl:for-each select="DATA/ROW">` but I can't seem to find the correct combination.

If one could also tell me how to add a sequential number before the `Nom` like so `1- Nom` I'd be a very happy camper.

Current output

```
<w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Some vulnerability</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Desired output

```
<w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>1- Some vulnerability</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>2- Some Other Vulnerability</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>3- Yet another vulnerability</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/DATA">

    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
      <xsl:text>progid="Word.Document"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
      <w:body>
        <xsl:for-each select="ROW">
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(count(preceding-sibling::ROW)+1,'- ',Nom)"/>
              </w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </w:body>
    </w:wordDocument>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A "more XSLT" solution would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/DATA">

    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
      <xsl:text>progid="Word.Document"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <w:wordDocument>
      <w:body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW"/>
      </w:body>
    </w:wordDocument>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ROW">
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(count(preceding-sibling::ROW)+1,'- ',Nom)"/>
        </w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output for both is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>1- Some vulnerability</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>2- Some Other Vulnerability</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>3- Yet another vulnerability</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply. Using those 2 XSLT give me the exact same result as mine plus a `1- ` in front of `Nom`. It seems the "loop" is still not working for some reason..

Comment: That's strange. Both of them result in basically the same output for me using Saxon, Xalan, xsltproc or Firefox' built-in XSLT processor. What are you using?

Comment: Ok, someone corrected my input XML. Seems that the space in `<Number of Affected>` was creating the problem. I change the name for `<NoAffected>` and it now process. I'm using the following linux script that use irb and nokogiri. 
irb -rrubygems <<EOF
require 'nokogiri'
#source = Nokogiri::XML( File.read('$XMLFILE') )
source = Nokogiri::XML( File.read('MyXML.xml') )
xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT( File.read('NessusTable.xslt') )
puts xslt.transform( source )  
exit
EOF

This is outside of this question, but if you know a free software that could to the trick in Windows I'd be happy to know!

Comment: That looks really complicated. Nokogiri uses libxslt in the background, and you can use it directly, like `xsltproc NessusTable.xslt MyXML.xml`. It's also available for Windows: http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html. There are also Saxon and Xalan, which are both cross-platform, and Microsoft's own XSLT processor: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714 (which obviously is not cross platform).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/DATA">

    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
      <xsl:text>progid="Word.Document"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <w:wordDocument
      xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">

      <w:body>
        <xsl:for-each select="//ROW">
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat($pos,'-')"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="Nom"/>
              </w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </w:body>
    </w:wordDocument>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```